# GraphQL with Typescript: Resolver Type Error

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

Using apollo-graphql, I've created an "account" type and accompanying resolver that uses [graphql-iso-date](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-iso-date). The configuration results in the following errors, any ideas on cause and resolution?

In the code included below, typedefs are combined into a collection from specific typedef modules.

> Type '{ Date: GraphQLScalarType; DateTime: GraphQLScalarType; Time:
>   GraphQLScalarType; } | { Query: AccountQueryResolver; }' is not
>   assignable to type 'IResolvers | IResolvers[] |
>   undefined'.
>
> Type '{ Date: GraphQLScalarType; DateTime:
>   GraphQLScalarType; Time: GraphQLScalarType; }' is not assignable to
>   type 'IResolvers | IResolvers[] | undefined'.
>
> Type '{ Date: GraphQLScalarType; DateTime: GraphQLScalarType; Time:
>   GraphQLScalarType; }' is not assignable to type 'IResolvers'. Property 'Date' is incompatible with index signature
>
> Type 'GraphQLScalarType' is not assignable to type '(() => any) |
>   GraphQLScalarType | IEnumResolver | IResolverObject |
>   IResolverOptions'.
>
> Type 'GraphQLScalarType'
>   is not assignable to type 'IResolverObject'.
>   Index signature is missing in type 'GraphQLScalarType'.

---

**TypeDefs Collection**

```
import CustomScalarTypeDefs from "./custom";
import QueryTypeDefs from "./query";
import AccountTypeDefs from "./account";

const TypeDefs = [CustomScalarTypeDefs, QueryTypeDefs, AccountTypeDefs];

export default TypeDefs;
```

---

**Custom Scalar TypeDefs**

```
import { gql } from "apollo-server-express";

const customScalarTypeDefs = gql`
  scalar Date
  scalar DateTime
  scalar Time
`;

export default customScalarTypeDefs;
```

---

**Query TypeDefs**

```
import { gql } from "apollo-server-express";

const QueryTypeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    account(id: String!): Account
  }
`;

export default QueryTypeDefs;
```

---

**Custom Scalar Resolver**

```
import { GraphQLDate, GraphQLDateTime, GraphQLTime } from "graphql-iso-date";

const CustomScalarResolver = {
  Date: GraphQLDate,
  DateTime: GraphQLDateTime,
  Time: GraphQLTime
};

export default CustomScalarResolver;
```

---

**Account Resolver**

```
import { QueryById } from "./signatures";
import Account, { AccountModel, AccountPayload } from "../../models/account";

interface AccountQueryResolver {
  account: (_: never, req: QueryById) => Promise<AccountModel | null>;
  createAccount: (
    parent: Account | null,
    { entity, name }: AccountPayload
  ) => Promise<AccountModel | null>;
}

const accountResolver: AccountQueryResolver = {
  account: (_, { id }): Promise<AccountModel | null> => {
    return Account.findOne({ _id: id }).exec();
  },
  createAccount: (_, { entity, name }): Promise<AccountModel | null> => {
    return Account.create({ entity, name });
  }
};

export default accountResolver;
```

Comment: `Account` defs?  I'm not ts expert ... `accountResolver` shouldn't be `IResolvers` type to be composable with other resolvers? means probably you don't need `AccountQueryResolver` (BTW strange name for interface) ... `CustomScalarResolver` IMHO doesn't make sense, (strange name, too) - resolver is a fn, not some object

Comment: @Ari did you ever find the solution for this? I ran into this problem as well